# Phalcon data to elastic search via beanstalkd

Tags: elasticsearch, phalcon, beanstalkd

Which would be efficient in terms of speed and resources?
Scenario 1
Write all data to a table where in each field represents ElasticSearch index?
Execute a cron or event to write data to ES index based on table data.
Scenario 2
Write all data to beanstalkd queue and fire an event to write job queue data to Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0):

I would say scenario 2 is your best choice and the one I've already done in the past, my only question would be, why not save it directly to elastic or is it to slow for you?

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd scenario is better, because it can help you to optimize resources of your servers
With the cronjob, you need scan your table everytime to find new data => not good for the performance
Hope it can help you